# What is the purpose of the [Key] attribute on a Primary Key in an asp.net MVC class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have read in various places, eg

http://techfunda.com/howto/132/primary-key-and-foreign-key-relationship-in-model

...that if you don't call the Id property in your model "Id" or "id" you need to add the annotation [Key], eg

```
[Key]
public int MyKey { get; set; }
```

...to it to tell the compiler it's the primary key in the database.

It seems like this may only be a requirement for Code First sites - although I can't find anything conclusive either way.

What is the purpose of [Key] and when should it be used?

Do I need to decorate any primary keys in models that are not called "Id" even when not building a Code First MVC site?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. It is needed for code first only

Comment: Also only needed if you want to persist this class. For example, if you use different model classes for Entity Framework and ViewModels (and map between them), you only need to attribute the EF Models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run code first and use this:

```
public class MyClass{
    [Key]
    public int MyKey { get; set; }
}
```

This will create in your database:

Table >> dbo.MyClass
Column >> MyKey IDENTITY NOT NULL

Answer (score 0):

When you create a script to create the table, you need to make sure it is a primary key and it is used for code first approach

```
public class NewClass{
  [key]
  public int MyKey {get; set;} 
  }
```